# Want to understand what's going on with linux command

Tags: linux, terminal, virtualenv

I am installing a virtualenv and want to understand what's going on.

$ curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py
- I understand curl fine

$ python virtualenv.py my_new_env
- Understand this, too

$ . my_new_env/bin/activate
- Here's where I get lost.  What is the period doing here?

(my_new_env)$ pip install ...
- What does it mean to have the parentheses here?  Does this use tell me I'm in a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot is a command that means to read and execute the contents of the given script in the current shell (normally running a shell script runs it in a new process.) Evaluating the script in the current shell can change the environment variables of the current shell, so the behavior of subsequent commands is affected.

I don't know for sure about the parentheses, but I don't think they're meant to be syntax you type. As they come before the '$' prompt, perhaps that's literally what you'll get as your new prompt after running the `activate` script, to show you that your environment has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

The dot is essentially an "execute" command — execute the commands in `my_new_env/bin/activate` as though they were typed into your prompt, essentially.

The parentheses shown in the prompt (at least in the tutorial instructions) then indicate that you're typing commands in your new virtual environment, and not in your original (real) environment.